# how the system knows whether we are uploading a csv fie or a xls file?

Tags: java

I am new to uploading a file to database.

I wants to know the process how the system will identify the file in uploading whether it is a csv file or a xml file?

What is the difference between csv file and xls file?

Benefits and drawbacks of each?

In my application it is configured with csv file upload but i am testing it for a xml file upload. Then it is raising an error as `string literal too long`.

Can you explain how to resolve this problem?

Comment: It is really not clear what your problem is. You are referring to uploading xls file, and then you mention xml file. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

From these pieces of information, I can give you a few pointers:

- `xls` is binary; patterns for identification are mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514847/how-to-identify-whether-an-excel-file-conforms-to-excel-95-or-excel-97-specificat)
- `csv` is text; how to identify if it is of a type you need; you have to know what's legal to be uploaded
- don't assume that a file ending with `xls` or `csv` is indeed of that type
- "string literal too long" seems to be an [Oracle error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01704_string_literal_too_long.htm); check your database column length and/or type
- `xml` files usually begin with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`
  , so you can use this pattern to identify them if you need to upload them; note that I said "usually"

Answer (score 0):

Any system or program expects a particular input file format.  Some can handle more than one input file format.

A csv file is a comma (or other delimiter) separated values file.
An xls file is a proprietary file structure used by Microsoft Excel.

More programs can read a csv file than an xls file.  Microsoft Excel can read both file formats.